# Mesh problem when smoothing intersecting cylinder in object

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

Im very new to blender so sorry if i don't explain very well. I made a hole in my object with a cylinder using the boolean intersect modifier but when i smooth the figure using the sub surf modifier its makes some geometry that i don't want there.

Well here are some screenshots:
**Before**[image: Before smoothing]
**After**[image]

Comment: watch this video to get more ideas on how to cut holes in blender: https://vimeo.com/68844586

Comment: You can also try to increase the crease

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The faces with 4+ sides are called Ngons.

Ngons are not easy to handle with subdivision surfaces. They don't give predictable results, you cannot easly controle them.

You can:

- Change your topology by converting all ngons and tris to **quads**, as they have user-easily-predictable results with subsurf, but you must do it manually and it will take lot of time.
- Convert ngons to **tris**, by triangulating and splitting your geometry (expecially concaves faces). This can be done automatically with the given commands with good results, but in will not be subsurfaced as percfectly as it would be done with only quads and will be hard to do further modeling onto.
- Don't use subsurface to smooth edges but **bevel** them (manually or with the modifier)